# Identify DRAM type in Linux /sys

Tags: linux, memory-card, dram

I'm trying to figure out the DRAM type of my computer's DRAM and the operation mode the DRAM is using.

On one of my very old computer with Linux 4.2.0-27-generic kernel installed, I can see the DRAM type is `Unbuffered-DDR3` by looking at `/sys/devices/system/edac/mc/mc0/dimm0/dimm_mem_type`.

However, on another computer with Broadwell process and Linux 4.1.3-040103-generic kernel installed, I didn't find the entry `mc0` under `/sys/devices/system/edac/mc`.

My question is:

Why is the `mc0` entry is not initialized by Linux on my new computer?

Is there any way I could see the information?

Comment: Or you could use also "lshw -class memory" or maybe "hwinfo".

Comment: Yes, one entry is as follows `     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM Synchronous 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: 18ASF2G72PZ-2G3B1
          vendor: Micron
          physical id: 2
          serial: 12217361
          slot: DIMMD1
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2400MHz (0.4ns)` I'm trying to find out the tech. document based on the product number, but failed. :-(

Answer (score 2):

I would use `dmidecode` for that task. It's an utility that can be installed in any linux distro and it dumps the contents of the DMI table (from the BIOS).

Usage: `sudo dmidecode -t memory`

You'll get one entry per memory chip as this one:

```
Handle 0x0037, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
    Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0033
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: 2
    Locator: XMM3
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 667 MHz
    Manufacturer: JEDEC ID:7F 7F 7F 7F B0 00 00 00
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: OCZ26671024V
```

Comment: Hi, yes, I did get the similar information. However, the Type is <Out of spec>. Is it because my DRAM is too new? I attached the information as below:

Comment: Handle 0x0060, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
 Array Handle: 0x005D
 Error Information Handle: Not Provided
 Total Width: 72 bits
 Data Width: 64 bits
 Size: 16384 MB
 Form Factor: DIMM
 Set: None
 Locator: DIMMD1
 Bank Locator: P0_Node0_Channel3_Dimm0
 Type: <OUT OF SPEC>
 Type Detail: Synchronous
 Speed: 2400 MHz
 Manufacturer: Micron
 Serial Number: 12217361
 Asset Tag: DIMMD1_AssetTag (date:16/13)
 Part Number: 18ASF2G72PZ-2G3B1  
 Rank: 1
 Configured Clock Speed: 2400 MHz
 Minimum voltage:  Unknown
 Maximum voltage:  Unknown
 Configured voltage:  Unknown